# Enable location "Name" in CiviEvent location configuration?

Tags: civievent

Is there a way to enter a location name above the address fields in CiviEvent location settings?

When configuring an event:
[image: event location config]

It would be nice to be able to place the name just above the address like this:

```
"Conference Center Name"
Street address 1
City, State, ZIP
```

Anybody know how to do this?

Comment: I know I could use the "Street address" fields but that seems hacky.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you enable the *Address Name* field globally, it will become available on the Event Location screen.

From `Administer CiviCRM → Localization → Address Settings` (or browse directly to /civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/address ), check the box for *Address Name* under the *Address Editing* section.

Comment: Nice, thank you @choster, I was not aware of this toggle. Exactly what I needed!